# Contextual type 'Void' (aka '()') cannot be used with array literal

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I´m getting this error in my code:

```
Contextual type 'Void' (aka '()') cannot be used with array literal
```

How I´m I suppose to solve this? Thanks!

I´m using the MVC model. Here is my code:

```
let users: [User] = {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("position")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let locationDict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            guard let lat = locationDict["latitude"] as? CLLocationDegrees,
                let long = locationDict["longitude"] as? CLLocationDegrees else { return }

            let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
            let userPosition = User(name: "Name", position: position)

            return [userPosition] //Here is my error 


        }


    })

}()

 override func cellClasses() -> [DatasourceCell.Type] {
    return [UserCell.self]
}

override func item(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> Any? {
    return users[indexPath.item]
}

override func numberOfItems(_ section: Int) -> Int {
    return users.count
}



}
```

My user property:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

struct User {

let name: String
let position: CLLocationCoordinate2D



}
```

And my Cell:

```
import LBTAComponents
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class UserCell: DatasourceCell, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate  {

let distanceSpan: Double = 500


override var datasourceItem: Any? {
    didSet {
        guard let user = datasourceItem as? User else { return }
        nameLabel.text = user.name
        MapView.setCenter(user.position, animated: false)

        MapView.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: user.position, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

        let locationPin = user.position
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = locationPin

        MapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        MapView.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)     

        }

   }
```

Comment: A return statement inside of a closure returns from the closure, not the outer function.  The closure has a `Void` return value so you can't return an array inside it.

Comment: Okay, I´m a bit new in Swift... Do you know how I can fix this? Or do it in another way? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some additional code from your project, showing how you use the `users` property? This is important in identifying how your current design needs to change in order to properly utilize the asynchronous callback from the database call.

Comment: So, let me know if it´s more you need!

Answer (score 0):

You are assinging a closure to `users`, which is declared as type `[User]` (Array with elements of type `User`).

As you are using MVC, I assume the code is inside a `UIViewController` use this (untested, but you get the idea):

```
import CoreLocation

struct User {
    var name:String
    var position:CLLocationCoordinate
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("position")
    var users: [User]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupRefObserver()
    }

    private func setupRefObserver() {
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let locationDict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                guard let lat = locationDict["latitude"] as? CLLocationDegrees,
                    let long = locationDict["longitude"] as? CLLocationDegrees else { return }

                let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
                let userPosition = User(name: "Name", position: position)

                users = [userPosition]
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I think the code work but I don´t know where to write it. I´ve edited a little bit.